# Why does publish run different code than Running in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, extjs, web-applications

I have an existing web application.  I have built my project and it runs perfectly find if I run it through the Visual Studio Run option.  It launches a browser window everything is fine.

The application is written in js and C# on the back end.  It uses the Sencha ExtJS framework.  All of the code changes were made to the javascript files.

When I use the deploy functionality, it creates a website on the wwwroot, but it does not include my changes, but rather the code before I made my changes.

I have tried to build/deploy both in debug and production configurations.  It doesn't seem to matter.

What have I done wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run Sencha CMD `sencha app build production`.

Without that the files and requirements are not updated and hence you do not see the updates.
If you run `sencha app watch` it will update your changes on the fly.

Comment: When I try to do this, I get all sorts of errors.  Cannot satisfy requirements for EXT....The following versions cannot be satisfied: root: ext@6.0.2.437 (no matches).  Please install a newer version of sencha cmd.  I'm 6.0.2.14.  However, when I try to do "Sencha app upgrade" i get the same message...please install a newer version...  I have 10 newer versions installed, but none of them work.  I'd love to try to install 437, but i couldn't find it on sencha website.

Comment: Download the latest version of sencha cmd. They are downwards compatible anyways.